# Android Things on Raspberry pi 3 not connecting using ADB Connect command

Tags: adb, iot, raspberry-pi3, android-things

I installed AndroidThings on Raspberry Pi 3. It boots up properly and showing IP address on display. Raspberry Pi 3 is connected to Ethernet.
Next, on my laptop, I updated my Android SDKs to latest version. I am using SDK 25.
Then I tried to connect to Pi 3 by following adb command:

adb connect IP address of Raspberry PI 3

It gives me error saying unable to connect.

I checked with adb devices command and it shows No Devices Attached.

I tried with both Windows 10 and Ubuntu and got the same error.
I tried connecting my android phone using

adb connect IP address of android phone

and it ran perfectly.

I am not sure what I am missing with Pi 3. Any help is appreciated.

Just for information, my laptop is running on WiFi on same network.

Comment: can you ping the IP or the raspberry pi? do you have a local firewall running that filter outbound connection?

Comment: @Proppy: Please post your comment as an answer. I would not have solved without your help.

Comment: glad it helped, feel free to post an answer to your own question with that you found out!

Comment: @Jatinder please move your comment explaining the answer to an answer and mark it as answered. Or delete this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue given by Proppy was sufficient for me to figure out what is happening. Here was the issue: I was not able to ping anything running on LAN.

Following is the solution in my case.

I am using D-Link router and there is NO rule of IP filtering.

The fix is to disable "Enable MultiAP Isolation" option.

Go to router setup page (192.168.1.1) --> Setup --> Wireless --> Wireless Basic and un-check the box "Enable MultiAP Isolation" and press "Apply" button.

This fixed the problem immediately and I could ping all devices on the LAN.